# How to read a yaml file to a string with the correct indentation

Tags: java, yaml

I need to read a `yaml` file and get the content of it to a `String`.

As the `yaml` format need the right indentation, I have to get the exact content as in the file. The normal way of reading a file in `java` doesn't work for me.

So if anyone can tell me how to read the content of a `yaml` file into a `String` variable.

Again the question is,

> How to read the content of a yaml file with the indentation and spaces and get the content of the file into a String variable in java? In other words, I need the content of the yaml file as it is to a String variable.

Comment: What is "the normal way of reading a file in Java"?

Comment: Using a BufferReader and a FileReader, this method just read the file ilne by line. I could print it out with the right indentation, but couldn't get the content to a String.

Comment: You could concatenate these lines, but it is probably easier not to read lines but blocks of characters and put these into a StringBuilder.

Comment: Thanks, in the first time I tried to concatenate the lines, there was a silly mistake. Figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you have figured it out, but here is the code for proper indentation.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class test {
    private static String FILENAME = "input.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(sCurrentLine);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuffer);
    }
}
```